# XML to HL7 translation using Mirth

Tags: xml, hl7, mirth

I am trying to get started with Mirth Connect. want to create a channel that would accept an XML and convert it in to HL7. As a result i wan to create an ADT and OBR messages.

Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: Can you provide me a sample of your input xml message.

Comment: You should have really searched before asking this question.
This kind of question has been answered before check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303623/convert-xml-to-hl7-messages-using-mirth-connect

Answer (score 0):

Am sharing my experience that how you can convert XML into HL7 using 
    Javascript codes for source transformer

```
   var length = msg['orderList']['order'].length();
   var rcount = 0;
   for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
   {
    var SEG = new XML("<OBR/>");
    SEG['OBR.1']['OBR.1.1']=i+1;
    SEG['OBR.16']['OBR.16.1']=msg['orderList']['order'][i]['provider'].toString();
    tmp['OBR'][i]=SEG;
    var reslen = msg['orderList']['order'][i]['result'].length();
    logger.info(reslen);
    for(var j=0;j<reslen;j++)
    {
        var RSEG = new XML("<OBX/>");
        RSEG['OBX.1']['OBX.1.1'] = rcount;
        RSEG['OBX.3']['OBX.3.1'] = msg['orderList']['order'][i]['result'][j]['resultcode'].toString();
        RSEG['OBX.3']['OBX.3.2']=msg['orderList']['order'][i]['result'][j]['text'].toString();
        RSEG['OBX.7'] = msg['orderList']['order'][i]['result'][j]['range'].toString();
        RSEG['OBX.6']['OBX.6.2'] = msg['orderList']['order'][i]['result'][j]['unit'].toString();
        tmp['OBX'][rcount]=RSEG;
        rcount++;
    }
}
logger.info(SerializerFactory.getSerializer('HL7V2').fromXML(tmp));

Dont forgot to create a HL& template in source outbound

**MSH|^~\&|||||||||
PID|||||||||||||||||||||||||||
ORC|||||||||||||||||||**



sample XML

<PatientOrder>
<patient>
<name><fullname>XXXXXXXXXXX, XXXX.</fullname><firstname>XXXXX</firstname><lastname>XXXXX</lastname></name>
<address>
<address1>XXXXXX XXXX XXXX Med XXXX</address1><address2>Information XXXXX Fl</address2><address3>XXXX XXXX St  </address3><address4>XXXXXX XXXXXX, XX XXXXX</address4><telephone>XXX/XXXX-XXXX</telephone><fax>XXX/XXX-XXX</fax><latitude>X2.XXXXX</latitude><longitude>-X1.XXXXX</longitude></address>
</patient>
<orderList>
 <order>
    <provider>57423</provider>
    <result>result
            <resultcode>7685-1</resultcode>
            <text>Hemoglobin test2</text>
            <resultdate></resultdate>
            <range>3to52</range>
            <unit>mg</unit>
        </result>
        <result>result
            <resultcode>7685-1</resultcode>
            <text>Hemoglobin test2</text>
            <resultdate></resultdate>
            <range>3to52</range>
            <unit>mg</unit>
        </result>
    </order>
<order>
    <provider>57423</provider>
    <result>result
            <resultcode>7685-1</resultcode>
            <text>Hemoglobin test2</text>
            <resultdate></resultdate>
            <range>3to52</range>
            <unit>mg</unit>
        </result>
    </order>
</orderList>
</PatientOrder>
```